# Start MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql

I Downloaded MySQL 5.7.10 to my Mac El Capitan 10.11.2 and installed, then started MySQL from Preferences.  Then I ran  "cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/".  Then when I do "ls" I see "mysql".  So all looks installed correctly.

I am now following the MySQL tutorial to start a database instance (ultimately I want to run some CREATE TABLE scripts).  But, "user$ mysql -u root" gives me -bash: mysql: command not found" .

My final goal is to do my SQL commands against a MySQL instances using an IDE like MySQL Workbench or Jetbrains Datagrip.  But I am stumped.

I do not get "mysql> "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`. If that works, then you need to [alter your $PATH](http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac) environment variable to include `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

Comment: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root        ------      that worked    -------    but then asked for password and the goofy password I was given appears to bonk /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p  !xLhj(MVg9:7    --------      -bash: !xLhj: event not found

Comment: Protect the password from interpretation by bash by enclosing it in quotes: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p "!xLhj(MVg9:7"`. Then change your password since you've posted it :)

Comment: I was in and started changing password but received an unknown > so I then tried exit and quit then finally I killed the terminal.  I did not intend to do all of that.  Now I can't log into mysql > .

Comment: See [Reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html).